# Prism + Xamarin Forms: around 1.2 seconds more compared to just using Xamarin Forms

Tags: prism

#### Package info

- Platform: Android
- Prism version: 7.0.0.336-pre
- Xamarin version: Android 8
- Other version info: Xamarin Forms, Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.121934

#### Repro steps

I create a simple XF + Prism app with DryIoc, based on the VS template.

I noticed a 1.2 seconds difference in the startup when using Prism compared to not using Prism.

When not using Prism, I still created the same view-model object and set it to View by calling in View's c-tor `BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel()`

I'm curious, based on the Prism for XF implementation, what's the main reason of this difference? Is it the dependency injection? DryIoc seem pretty fast though.